# towgs Definition for European Datum 1950

Tags: coordinate-system, r, datum

I am new to all things GIS so apologies for a basic questions. I am trying to specify the CRS of a climatic raster layer in R. It is an equal area projection based on Europe Equidistant Conic and the datum is D European 1950. Can anyone help me specifiy the argument in R?

projection(myraster) = CRS("+proj=eqdc +ellps=???+ datum=???")

Many thanks if you can help!

Comment: Is the map area in the south Permian Basin?

Comment: In your other answer you refer to ECA&D E-OBS - where did you find that these data are provided in European 1950 datum? Please indicate the URL or reference...

Comment: I assume tsutsume wants to make a map in that projection. The data looks like degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Europe Equidistant Conic" is also coded as [ESRI:102031](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102031/) and its Proj.4 definition is:

```
+proj=eqdc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +lat_1=43 +lat_2=62 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs
```

Answer (score 1):

QGIS reports European Datum ED50 as

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```

But there are als definitions

```
IGNF:ED50G +proj=longlat +towgs84=-84.0000,-97.0000,-117.0000 +a=6378388.0000 +rf=297.0000000000000 +units=m +no_defs
ED50(ED77) EPSG:4154 +proj=longlat +ellps=intl +towgs84=-117,-132,-164,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```

It mainly depends on what part of Europe your data is from. But I doubt if it has a great impact on the analysis of your data.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response. It is the whole extent of Europe. The original climatic data set is from the E-OBS gridded climatic data set. I will try your suggestions.